# How to print string loop 0000,....,0009,000A,000B,....,000F,0010,...,4000 with Python

Tags: python, string

Could you help me?

I wish have a array string:
[plz see photo here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y78Wo.png)

0000
0001
....
0009
000A
000B
000C
000D
000E
000F
0010
0011
....
001A
001B
001C
....
....
1900
1A00
1B00
....
....
2999
299A
299B
....
....
3999
399A
399B
....
....
3EFF
....
....
3FFC
3FFD
3FFE
3FFF
4000

I try with my code:

```
    print("\n".join(['{0:04}'.format(num) for num in range(0, 4001)]))
```

Result:

```
    0000
    0001
    ....
    ....
    0008
    0009
    ....
    ....
    3996
    3997
    3998
    3999
    4000
```

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using f-strings (more modernly-Pythonic than `format()`) you can do this:

```
print("\n".join([f"{num:04X}" for num in range(0x4001)]))
```

The `04X` format specifier means a zero-padded 4-digit string of capitalized hex digits.

Comment: I am so dumb that I used `int('4001', 16)` instead 0x4001 (+1)

Answer (score 1):

you can try

```py
[hex(i)[2:].zfill(4) for i in range(0x4001)]
```